# detect and select nonblack images in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image

I am currently working on a media project. We've shooted looong clips, mainly dark if not black. I have decomposed these clips into their frames (>500k single frames) and put them in some folders. Now, my goal is to find out and select those frames that are not black or mainly dark: it's around a thousand out of the total.

This seems a job that a simple Python script can handle without too much effort. I know that scikit-image is quite common to work with images, but don't know how to come up with a script that does the job neatly. I have some experience with scientific programming but this with images manipulation is a bit out of my field.

For example, [this image should be reported as black](https://ibb.co/r6Jrn3L) and thus ignored, while [this other one](https://ibb.co/0m9Cdjm), although in low light, should be kept as good.

Ideally, it would be optimal to have a script that uses one or more criteria to determine if an image is totally dark or not, and in the latter case put it into another folder for human (me) inspection.

Any help is exteremely appreciated!

Comment: What Operating System do you use? And can you please add your images into your question so we can get access - currently they are password protected. Thanks.

Comment: Windows, fixed the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opencv is enough to solve this problem.

use `np.mean(image, axis=2)` to get mean of different channels, then you can easily check the black ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the mean of each image very simply without writing any code using **ImageMagick** which is available for Windows, Linux and macOS.

Like this:

```
magick identify -format '%[fx:mean*255] %f\r\n' black.jpg
1.01936 black.jpg
```

and:

```
magick identify -format '%[fx:mean*255] %f\r\n'  nonblack.jpg
1.72921 nonblack.jpg
```

To improve performance, I would use **GNU Parallel** on macOS or Linux, but in Windows, I would open a new command prompt for each directory and run several scripts in parallel, or start one script processing all the files ending in 0 or 1, a second one processing files ending in 2 or 3, a third one processing files ending in 4,5 or 6 and a final one processing files ending in 7,8 or 9.

---

If I was doing it in Python I would use a multiprocessing pool to speed things up, by the way.

Comment: Why would you not use GNU Parallel under CygWin on Microsoft Windows?

Comment: @OleTange Because that would mean I would have to install **two** things I don't like or want on my computer - Windows **and** Cygwin

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the replies, taking a 'mean' of the image helped. After reading in the image, I compute `np.mean(img, axis = 2).mean()` so that I have the mean of the three colour channels. If this mean is low (<2) then the image is discarded, otherwise the file is copied to another folder.

The code is not really time efficient as it takes ~3 hours for 200k files, but does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use PIL (Python Image Library).

I did a quick search for code that calculates the average of an image and found this snippet:

[Image Average Color](http://blog.gordn.org/2012/06/python-calculating-average-color-of.html)

```
import Image

def get_average_color((x,y), n, image):
    """ Returns a 3-tuple containing the RGB value of the average color of the
    given square bounded area of length = n whose origin (top left corner) 
    is (x, y) in the given image"""

    r, g, b = 0, 0, 0
    count = 0
    for s in range(x, x+n+1):
        for t in range(y, y+n+1):
            pixlr, pixlg, pixlb = image[s, t]
            r += pixlr
            g += pixlg
            b += pixlb
            count += 1
    return ((r/count), (g/count), (b/count))

image = Image.open('test.png').load()
r, g, b = get_average_color((24,290), 50, image)
print r,g,b
```

Maybe you could just iterate through all of the images in your folder and log (or copy) ones that are above a certain values.

There's probably a more elegant way to do this using PIL but maybe this will get you started.

Hope it helps!